# Sum the values which is regex match based field object in mongdb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In Mongiodb I have a object like this:

```
{
    "Brand" : "YY1",
    "Parent Company" : "XXX",
    "Week Ending 02-12-14" : 339.154407659,
    "Week Ending 01-19-14" : 458.614275287,
}
{
    "Brand" : "YY2",
    "Parent Company" : "XXX",
    "Week Ending 01-12-14" : 339.154407659,
    "Week Ending 03-19-14" : 458.614275287,
}
{
    "Brand" : "YY1",
    "Parent Company" : "XXX",
    "Week Ending 01-12-14" : 339.154407659,
    "Week Ending 04-19-14" : 458.614275287,
}
{
    "Brand" : "YY2",
    "Parent Company" : "XXX",
    "Week Ending 01-12-14" : 339.154407659,
    "Week Ending 01-20-14" : 458.614275287,
    "Week Ending 04-19-14" : 458.614275287,
}
```

I tried like this. I should query like the field must start with Week Ending has need to be sum of and parent company as "XXX":

```
db.getCollection('collection name').aggregate([{
    "$addFields": {
        "finder": {
            "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "finder.k": /^Week Ending/
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "Brand",
        "sum": {
            "$sum": "Week Ending 01-12-14"
        }
    }
}])
```

Bbut I can sum the field if it defined like Week Ending 01-12-14, but I want to sum the field which start with Week Ending.

In my collection there will be object may contain Week Ending or not.
But if the brand object doesnt contain Week Ending ,pos value will 0.0,

And my expected result like this,

```
[{
    "parent":"XXX"
    "Brand" : "YY1",
    "pos_value":"float values"**(sum of all values starts with week ending in all YY1 brand object)**
}, {
    "parent":"XXX"
    "Brand" : "YY2",
    "pos_value":"float values"**(sum of all values starts with week ending in all YY2 brand object)**
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this aggregation that utilises [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/):

```
db.getCollection('collection name').aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "week_sum": {
                    "$reduce": {
                        "input": {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"},
                                "as": "field",
                                "cond": {"$gt": [{"$size": {"$split": ["$$field.k", "Week Ending"]}}, 1]}
                            }
                        },
                        "initialValue": 0,
                        "in": {"$sum": ["$$value.v", "$$this"]}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "Brand",
                "parent": {"$first": "$Parent Company"},
                "$sum": {"$sum": "$week_sum"}
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "parent": "$parent",
                "brand": "$_id",
                "pos_value": "$sum"
            }
        }
    ])
```

With that said this document structure is highly unscalable. I recommend you re-think it and do something similar to the following:

```
{
    "Brand" : "YY1",
    "Parent Company" : "XXX",
    "Weeks": [
       {"date": ISODate("02-12-14"), value: 339.154407659),
       {"date": ISODate("01-19-14"), value: 458.614275287}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i will check